# How to get the status of the consent screen from not published to published

Tags: api, oauth, screen, status, verification

I have set up google API & Service with OAuth credentials and authorized redirect URL that uses a domain that has been verified in the domain verification tab.

What else do I need to do to get the Verification status from Not published to published and stop having the warning: "OAuth is limited to 100 sensitive scope logins until the OAuth consent screen is published", whenever I create a new OAuth client ID web application credentials?

Do I just have to wait?

Thank you.

I'd like to have the verification status of the OAuth consent screen tab set to "published" so I stop receiving the warning about the limit of 100.

Comment: Do you have any solution?